# Is it possible to automatically import mDNS entries into a bind9 .local zone file?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, avahi, mdns

It's nice to have a [zeroconf setup with mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#Avahi), but some of my machines (like docker containers) do not contain the avahi-daemon and by that they are not able to resolve .local  hostnames. Now I could create manually a zone file for all my .local hostnames, but by that I would break the zeroconf concept.

Is there a solution available that automatically imports all mDNS entries into a bind9 .local zone file?